# DLL File missing after Wine upgrade to version 1.4.1

Tags: linux, macos, dll, wine

I used to run a few Windows applications via Wine 1.4.0 (installed through homebrew) on OSX Mountain Lion and after I updated to 1.4.1 (again via homebrew), I get the following error whenever trying to run any windows application:

```
wine: failed to initialize: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/wine/1.4.1/lib/wine/ntdll.dll.so, 258): image not found
```

Any ideas about how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That's clearly an installer/packaging/homebrew problem, has nothing to do with wine itself.